# Curl 'GET' successfully, but Curl 'POST' unsuccessfully

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot + Rest + Spring Security (Basic Auth) as my back end API.
I'm able to curl with GET, but i'm not able to curl with POST.

I'm using application.property + WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to set my security.

Application.property

```
spring.security.user.name=a
spring.security.user.password=b
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")    
public class ExploreController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExploreController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/exploregethead", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HashMap<String, String> exploregethead(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(key);
            logger.info(key + " : " + value);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/exploreposthead", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<String, String> exploreposthead(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(key);
            logger.info(key + " : " + value);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

for CORS

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }

}
```

Both rest request are similar except one is accepting GET and another is accepting POST.

I'm using curl to test it, and i have two different output.

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Authorization:Basic YTpi" http://localhost:8080/api/exploregethead
```

[GET Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xeW4.png)

When i using curl to POST the API, I facing 401 error

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization:Basic YTpi" http://localhost:8080/api/exploreposthead
```

[POST Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eolu.png)

I did try to use rest client to POST the API, it prompt me to input the username and password. But i entered the username 'a' and password 'b', it still not working.

[Rest Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NDkI.png)

Please advise part i had done wrongly. Thanks.

Comment: Your controller resource is just "/exploreposthead" but in your curl commands you query '/api/exploreposthead'. Try to choose one and use it in both places.

Comment: Thanks. I did add the header in code. Just edited the question to include @RequestMapping(value="/api")

Comment: What is the response code you are getting? it fails in which layer security layer or before that itself?

Comment: No error message return. I set the break point, it didn't hit the controller, but it hit CorsFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the tutorial below.
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-spring-security-example/

Thanks mkyong!

> Application.property - **removed**
>
> Controller - **no change**
>
> CorsFilter - **no change**
>
> WebSecurityConfig - **update below**

package app.mootor.api;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");

    }

    // Secure the endpoins with HTTP Basic authentication
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                //HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/aapi/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/aapi/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }

}
```

Test GET

```
curl localhost:8080/api/explore -u user:password
```

Test POST

```
curl localhost:8080/api/exploreposthead -X POST -u user:password
```